# Pandas | Save Index Value of last row

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, col

Trying to find the last index value and save to variable but I cant seem to pull only the index column alone.  I want to be able to use the date to determine if new values have been generated.

Process is as follows:

1. Parse excel for latest (last) date
2. Save latest (last) date to variable
3. Continue to monitor for new entries and save latest (last) to that variable again.

`df = pd.read_csv('USDT_XRP_4HOUR_JAN_2017.csv', index_col='date',delimiter=',') 
print('INDEX - LAST 1 LINES')
print(df.iloc[-1:,-1])
print('END OF INDEX - LAST 1 LINES')`

OUTPUT

`END OF INDEX - LAST 1 LINES
date
2018-09-18 10:55:00    0.274509
Name: high, dtype: float64
END OF INDEX - LAST 1 LINES`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access the index by the `index` attribute of the dataframe. To get the last value, you could do this

```
df.index[-1]
```

or

```
df.index.values[-1]
```